# Vue js, how to give `this` a type?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am working on Vue (3.2.13) for the first time, I have worked with typescript.

I am getting this warning. `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)`

In react based environments, all I did was `(this as any)` and it seemed to work, but here it does not.

```
<template>
  <component :is="this.$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
    <router-view />
  </component>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

How do I properly provide type for `<component :is="this.$route.meta.layout || 'div'">`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which vue version are you using?

Comment: FYI, you don't really need to use `this` in the template, as the component instance is the implied context.

Comment: Vue version is 3.2.13.

Comment: Yes, but if I am to give `this`, how will I assign a type to it?

Comment: As tony says, just miss out `this.`. Otherwise you're effectively referencing a `this` property *within* your component which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, it is working but now I want to know if I can actually give a type to this.

Comment: The issue still occurs if `this` is used in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the template you only need to use "$".

```
        <h2>{{ $route.params.id }}</h2>
```